# DXA 1.2: Controlling CacheProvider from Webapp

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.2

Currently, in DXA 1.2, cache provider is configured as `cacheProvider` bean in `spring-context.xml` in `dxa-tridion-provider` within `dxa-framework` project, which is used to configure `PageFactory` instance.

This configuration is valid for scenarios where we would like to continue using `EhCacheProvider`. But consider a situation where we would like to control the cache provider implementation from respective web application, for example configure `NoCacheProvider` instead of `EhCacheProvider`.

In this case, it would require us to change the `spring-context.xml` within `dxa-tridion-framework`, which is not recommended as individual applications are not suppose to make changes to dxa framework.

SDL provides an alternative to define this bean in `spring-context.xml` of web app. But this config will not be considered because bean definition is picked from configuration within `dxa-tridion-provider` described in the beginning.

Kindly, share your views or suggestions.

Comment: It would be good if the default configuration is taken out of `spring-context.xml` in `dxa-tridion-provider`. 

Can it be a potential change request for `DXA 1.2` to remove the default configuration and let main web app provide the bean definition.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve with this comment. If you want DXA team to consider changes to the application, please file it as an issue here: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues

Comment: @NunoLinhares yes you are correct I should raise an issue. As we need to update the config file in tridion provider to not have CacheProvider configured and leave it to web app to configure.

Comment: @Puneetkankane: was the issue created? I couldn't find it on GitHub.
Maybe post the link here as well? Thanks